# Is there a way in Android to programmatically get the default speaker or microphone or any peripheral

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager, peripherals

Let's say I have connected multiple external speakers and also if the device has inbuilt speakers.
How do I get the information on which speaker is the default one. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can call:

- [AudioManager#getDevices(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#getDevices(int))

or

- [AudioRouting#getPreferredDevice()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRouting#getPreferredDevice())

To get:

- [AudioDeviceInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioDeviceInfo)

If that is not enough to help you, then you need to provide more information about what you are using and what you are trying to do.